# library writing syntax like model/controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Using CodeIgniter 2, when writing library :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->model('one_model');
}

public function test()
{
    $this->ci->one_model->blabla();
}
```

I'm curious in library, can I write it like in controller/model style (without the ->ci) ?

```
$this->one_model->blabla();
```

I ask this because I sometimes re-write model codes as a library, for better logic - db separation. 
Any help appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `__get` function in class

```
class Custom
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
       // construct
    }

    public function __get($var)
    {
       return get_instance()->$var;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $this->one_model->blabla();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx so much Bora. I've seen __get many times but don't sure what its for.